# Fancybox v.2.1.2 not opening on IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, fancybox-2

I am using Fancybox v.2.1.2 in Wordpress (not a plugin). In IE7, I have the loading but it does not opening anything at all.

Here is my JS code

```
<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.2"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.2" media="screen" />
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery("a.fancybox").fancybox({
        padding : 0
    });  
});
</script>
```

And here is my code in my page :

```
<a href="/path/to/images/P1050615.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery[283]"></a>
<div class="hidden">
 <a class="fancybox" href="/path/to/images/P1050616.jpg" rel="gallery[283]"><img src="/path/to/images/P1050616.jpg"></a>
 <a class="fancybox" href="/path/to/images/P1050617.jpg" rel="gallery[283]"><img src="/path/to/images/P1050617.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

I am using the HTML5 Doctype but even when I am changing it, it does not change anything.

Comment: Does it work in other browsers?  Are you adding jQuery library also?

Comment: Does it work in IE8 or IE9? IE is very picky about javascript, a missed ',' or ';' will cause it to fail, also using console.log will stop the script since console isn't defined by default. Seems to me the problem isn't really your fancybox code but something else.

Comment: Yes it does work on IE8 and IE9 and yes I added Jquery Library before my fancybox script.

I guess it is something else... the console just give me this error but it is there in IE8 and IE9 also.
'SEC7115: Styles of visible links and consulted may have a different color. Some styles were not applied to the link consulted.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that this is a bug (it's not your fault, it's not your code).

I have contacted directly the developer and he confirmed to me that the issue is expecting to be fixed in the next commit.

You may rollback to version v2.1.1 in the meantime.

**UPDATE** : Fancybox v2.1.3 has been released

Changelog
Version 2.1.3 - October 23, 2012

- Fixed #426 - Broken IE7
- Fixed #423 - Background flickering on iOS
- Fixed #418 - Automatically Grow/Shrink and Center
- Updated the script to work with jQuery 1.6
- Media helper supports YouTube video series

Comment: @Sducasse : version 2.1.3 is available and IE7 issue fixed.

Comment: Yes, sorry. At least I know that there indeed are people who care about IE7 :)

Comment: You'd be suprise to see how many people are still using this old browser. At least, we don't have to care about IE6 anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

I find the bug ... not in Fancybox but into IE7, IE8, and IE9 !

If you create an iframe with a page that contain the following CSS, then IE do not display the page :

```
html { position: relative; }
```

If you know the webmaster of the destination page, ask him to remove this CSS declaration, the display of it's page should not change ... otherwise, no solution to my knowledge!

That's all !