# In jquery fancybox ajax modal popup not showing for ie 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer

Hello I have used JQuery fancy box first time in that i have show all the menu list on click on specific item the page is render properly in iframe,but if ajax model popup is already present in rendered page then it is not showing properly for IE 7 but working properly for IE9-10,

Here i have paste my sample code,

```
       function showPopUp(PanelName) 
    {
        $.fancybox({
            width: '95%',
            href: 'NewMenuList.aspx?Panel=' + PanelName,
            type: 'iframe',                
        });
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
<a id="example1" class="portalMenu" onclick="showPopUp('Master')" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <img alt="Master" src="../Images/Portal_Master.png" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a data-type and download the last fancybox... It should work in IE7

```
<a class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="/demo/iframe.html">Iframe</a>

$(".various").fancybox();
```

Use it like this

Comment: Hello PoWeR thanks 4 your replay,but problem remains same.Ajax modal popup not showing properly for IE7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978885/fancybox-v-2-1-2-not-opening-on-ie7

Found this read.. I think is a bug in fancybox..